# Etimologia das gírias "chupista" e "chupim"

Tags: etimologia, ortografia, origem-histórica

As gírias *chupista* e *chupim*, respectivamente de Portugal e Brasil, possuem significados ligeiramente similares, assim como o radical *chup-*.

Elas possuem a mesma origem? Ou é apenas coincidência?

Comment: Eu argumentaria que o radical na verdade é [chup]; pois em ‘chupista’, ‘ista’ é sufixo grego, enquanto que o ‘im’ parece terminação típica de corruptelas brasileiras (v.g. maneirinho -> maneirim).

Comment: Chupim é o nome do pássaro que deu origem à gíria, dado o seu comportamento. Parece nome indígena.

Comment: Luciano, existe também a forma, que o Houaiss diz ser menos recomendável, *chopim*. Elas tem pronúncias diferentes? Em Portugal são iguais, o ***o*** de *chopim* seria normalmente pronunciado ***u***; mas creio que no Brasil é ***ô*** ou ***ó***, certo?

Comment: @Jacinto nunca ouvi chopim e imaginando agora a pronúncia, soariam muito indistintas (pelo menos no meu sotaque - paulistano).

Comment: Então no teu sotaque *ch**upim*** rima com *m**otim*** e *b**otim***? (No meu rimam, mas pensei que no Brasil não rimassem.)

Comment: @Jacinto Deve ser por isso que algumas pessoas escrevem buteco e butiquim e outras boteco e botequim, esse O e U soam muito parecidos.

Comment: Eu estava a imaginar a passagem do tupi *xo'pi* para o português *chupim*, a passagem do ***o*** ao ***u***,  influenciada por *chupar*, . Mas se também no Brasil se reduz esse /o/ a /u/, essa passagem pode simplesmente ser o resultado das tendências fonológicas da língua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As etimologias são diversas: ***chupim*** vem do tupi *xo’pi* (Houaiss, Lisboa, 2002); ***Chupista*** vem de *chupar*, que embora tendo origem incerta, está atestado em português no século XV e em espanhol no XIII, portanto demasiado cedo para virem do tupi.

### Origem de *chupim*

[*Chupim* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/chupim) ou *chopim* (alternativa menos recomendável segundo o dicionário Houaiss) é um pássaro brasileiro que, tal como o cuco no Velho Mundo, pões os ovos em ninhos de aves de outras espécies, para que estas os choquem e lhes criem os filhotes. Inspirando-se nestes pássaros, a linguagem popular passou também a chamar *chupim* ao marido que vive à custa da mulher. Esta é pelo menos a opinião de vários autores, começando com Monteiro Lobato em 1919:

[image]
[Monteiro Lobato, “Romance do Chopim”, *Cidades Mortas*, São Paulo, 1921 [1ª ed. 1919], p. 68.](https://archive.org/stream/cidadesmortasco00lobagoog#page/n77/mode/2up/search/chopim)

Esta é primeira referência que eu encontrei a *chupim* nesta aceção, embora este chupim fosse diferente do que eu imaginava: vivia às custas da mulher, mas aparentemente era também um fraco, e ela é que vestia calças. Para designar simplesmente o pássaro, as ocorrências mais antigas que encontrei são de [1863 (para *chupim*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=p7oyAQAAMAAJ&pg=PR39-IA42&dq=chupins&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIr_nay_HaAhXjlOAKHXhJAiIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=chupins&f=false) e [1876 (*chopim*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ToQ6AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA104&dq=chopins&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH7v_mzPHaAhUiiOAKHZXwAA0Q6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=chopins&f=false), ambas anteriores às indicadas no Houaiss.

### Origem de *chupista* em *chupar*

Agora, eu não excluiria a possibilidade de *chupar*, ou mesmo *chupista*, terem influenciado o sentido figurado de *chupim*, uma vez que *chupar* é no português uma palavra bem mais antiga, mesmo nas aceções figuradas relevantes. O significado original de *chupar* parece ser ‘sugar’. As aceções figuradas ‘exaurir, esgotar (riquezas)’ (presente em dicionários antigos) e ‘explorar, aproveitar-se (de alguém)’ ([Aulete 7 e 9](http://www.aulete.com.br/chupar)) já estão presentes nas obras de autores do século XVI (Fr. Amador Arraes, Jorge Ferreira de Vasconcellos; ver referências no dicionário de [Moraes Silva de 1858](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KXLlRqBwZ90C&pg=PA464&lpg=PA464&dq=%22Chupar%20fig%20exhaurir%20esgottar%22&source=bl&ots=_hxZUnHg7R&sig=zbHao9nIALRCmm0X52Arxen_mwY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjamqjGwfHaAhUyzlkKHTG0D4EQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Chupar%20fig%20exhaurir%20esgottar%22&f=false)).

[*Chupista* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/chupista) está atestado na aceção de *bêbado* em 1803 (Houaiss) e de “o que vive à custa alheia” no [dicionário de Eduardo Faria de 1849](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gRI1zs6_zxYC&pg=RA1-PA200&dq=Chupista&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibjMLHxPHaAhWxuVkKHZvTBQQQ6AEIuQEwFA#v=onepage&q=Chupista&f=false). Neste [livro de 1870](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_plkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA132&dq=%22chupista%20de%20dinheiro%20e%20de%20tolinas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZutfAyfHaAhXuqlkKHY3VBnEQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22chupista%20de%20dinheiro%20e%20de%20tolinas%22&f=false) atribui-se “chupista de dinheiro e de tolinas” a Bocage, que morreu em 1805, mas eu não sei se a autoria de Bocage é genuína.

Veio-me primeiro à ideia que as aceções figuradas de *chupar* se inspirassem nos bebés, que só chupam (além de sujar fraldas). Tanto que em Portugal também se chama a esse comportamento parasítico [*andar à mama* (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mama). Mas existem outras possibilidades: desde há muito que se diz que insetos, morcegos, etc. chupam o sangue. Por exemplo, encontramos na obra de Francisco Manuel de Mello (1608-66) temos uma referência a [sanguessugas que nos chupam o sangue.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=URhxSzKOEZoC&pg=PA193&dq=%22s%C3%A3o%20como%20as%20sanguessugas%22%20%22pando-vos%20o%20sangue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl1_-ZgfLaAhULQBQKHeHcAaoQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22s%C3%A3o%20como%20as%20sanguessugas%22%20%22pando-vos%20o%20sangue%22&f=false)

### Origem de *chupar*

Entretanto, quanto à origem de *chupar* é que há menos certezas. O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) diz que é provavelmente de origem onomatopaica, opinião partilhada pelo [dicionário da Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=94gRaCx) em relação ao *chupar* espanhol. Antenor Nascentes [(Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa)](https://archive.org/stream/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/DicionarioEtimolgicoDaLinguaPortuguesa#page/n155/mode/2up) sugere que seja “forma dissimilada de *chuchar*”, a que foram propostas várias origens latinas (página anterior do dicionário). A. Coelho, mencionado por Nascentes, diz que *chupar* tem a mesma origem que o francês antigo *souper* (‘sorver’) e o inglês *sip* (‘bebericar’) e *sup* (‘beber’). E isto remete-nos para o proto-germânico **supanan* (ver [*sip*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sip) e especialmente [*sup*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sup?ref=etymonline_crossreference) no Etymoline), que deu origem também a várias palavras parecidas noutras línguas germânicas, e que teria vindo de uma raiz protoindo-europeia de onde teria vindo também o latim *sugere*, que deu origem ao português *sugar*

Comment: Antes de terminar de ler eu já sabia quem era o autor da resposta. +1